# Многомерный массив

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив:

```
$cars = array(
'1' => array('id'=>1, 'producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'10', 'price'=>'100', 'uniq'=>'1#10#100'),
'2' => array('id'=>1, 'producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'10', 'price'=>'100', 'uniq'=>'1#10#100'),
'3' => array('id'=>1, 'producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'110', 'uniq'=>'1#0#110'),
'4' => array('id'=>2, 'producer'=>'audi', 'model'=>'a1', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'90', 'uniq'=>'2#0#90'),
'5' => array('id'=>2, 'producer'=>'audi', 'model'=>'a1', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'90', 'uniq'=>'2#0#90')
);
```

uniq формируется по принципу id#sale#price.

Нужно из него получить массив:

```
$unique_cars = array(
'1' => array('id'=>1, 'producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'10', 'price'=>'100', 'quantity'=>2),
'2' => array('id'=>1, 'producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'110', 'quantity'=>1),
'3' => array('id'=>2, 'producer'=>'audi', 'model'=>'a1', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'90', 'quantity'=>2)
);
```

**Всем спасибо за участие, жалко что нельзя выбрать сразу несколько правильных ответов :)**

Comment: @Зоркий, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я не прошу готового решения, достаточно алгоритма.

Comment: Я не вижу закономерности, по которой получился результирующий массив. Может расскажешь, по какому принципу он должен формироваться?

Comment: А почему $unique_cars['3']==$unique_cars['4']? Так и должно быть?

Comment: в массиве cars есть uniq, он и служит связующим звеном при формировании массива $unique_cars, поэтому unique_cars[1] получена из $cars[1] и $cars[2], и $unique_cars quantity = 2

Comment: А почему в элементах $unique_cars все 'id' одинаковые? Так и должно быть?

Comment: @Зоркий, лично мне Ваш комментарий ничего не объяснил :) По какой системе 2 элемента cars могут собраться в один unique_cars? в случае с последними двумя в unique_cars как понять, из чего они собраны? И почему они полностью идентичны?
Задача поставлена как-то неполно...

Comment: Нет, с id опечатка вышла, я их поправил.

Comment: @Зоркий, повторяю вопрос: почему $unique_cars['3'] равен $unique_cars['4']?

Comment: Опечатка !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$unique_cars = array();

foreach ($cars as $car)
    {
    if (!isset($unique_cars[$car['uniq']]))
        {
        $car['quantity'] = 1;
        $unique_cars[$car['uniq']] = $car;
        unset($unique_cars[$car['uniq']]['uniq']);
        }
    else
        $unique_cars[$car['uniq']]['quantity']++;
    }

// странные ключи массивов (строковые numeric, да еще не от 0, а от 1)
// но это твое дело

$indexes = array();

while (count($indexes) < count($unique_cars))
    $indexes[] = strval(count($indexes) + 1);

$unique_cars = array_combine($indexes, $unique_cars);

var_dump($unique_cars);
```

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм таков:

1. Запускаем цикл по всем элементам `$cars`
2. Каждый элемент добавляем в массив `$unique_cars`, предварительно сравнивая необходимые поля: если они идентичны, то увеличиваем `quantity` соответствующего элемента `$unique_cars`

В чем возникли сложности?

Comment: По алгоритму, я подумал и решил не делать промежуточный массив, а сразу делать $unique_cars, добавив туда uniq и на этапе формирования массива делать проверку, а далее просто увеличивать значение quantity

Answer (score 1):

По мне так много лишнего в результирующем массиве.

Должно быть так

```
$unique_cars = array(
'1' => array('producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'10', 'price'=>'100', 'quantity'=>2),
'2' => array('producer'=>'bmw', 'model'=>'x5', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'110', 'quantity'=>1),
'3' => array('producer'=>'audi', 'model'=>'a1', 'sale'=>'0', 'price'=>'90', 'quantity'=>2)
);
```

Comment: Под много лишнего в массиве подразумевается отдельно ключа id?